# Reimport ssh certificate after every reboot for GIT PUSH over ssh to work

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, git

I am using OSX 10.8 on my macbook air, i have git configured to push my repository to an EC2 instance via ssh. Everything works fine with that.

The only issue is that after every reboot, I have to `ssh-add certname.pem` in order to allow GIT to connect to my ec2 instance over SSH.

I am not sure if this is just an overlooked configuration issue, or if there is a more indepth reason for this.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you use

```
ssh-add -K [keyfile]
```

to add the info to your Keychain? Then it will be there next time you start a terminal while authed to that keychain

Comment: That did the trick. so ssh-add only adds the cert for the length of the session. While -K adds it to the OSX keychain and persistent across multiple sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set up a key with no password and [have git/ssh use that key as its SSH `IdentityFile`](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/tell-git-which-private-key-to-use)?
(although `ssh-keygen` asks you for a passphrase when you generate a key you can just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and the resulting key won't require a passphrase to use).

Since you want to automatically re-add this key you're bypassing any security that using a key would give you anyway, so there's no practical difference between a passwordless key and one that the agent automatically imports.

---

Obviously you don't want this key to be able to do anything except access your `git` server (in case someone gets their hands on the private half of the key you don't want them running commands as you!)

Comment: There is not a password on the Cert, i am just using the one i setup the ec2 instance with. is that bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to setup script to add the pem to OSX's keychain
add below line to your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.zshrc if you are using zsh)

```
ssh-add -K certname.pem
```

Check out this https://superuser.com/a/409316/41202 for more details

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This is an unfortunate interaction with EC2's ssh design. You're strongly encouraged to use pem files to reach instances, hence why you `ssh -i <aws.pem>` in all their connectivity examples...

How about a git alias? I haven't tested this, as I don't have an EC2 instance at which to push, but something like:

```
git config alias.ec2push "!sh -c 'ssh-add certname.pem && git push $1 $2'"
```

Then you'd push with:

```
git ec2push <repo> <branch>
```

Comment: My comment was lost when this got migrated from SO, but faced with this problem I'd use one of the other answers before this one. I'm leaving it up in case anyone finds it useful, but personally I'd rather deal with the keys than with an alias.